# How unique a EWS ItemId is?

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In my application's database I store user's emails. I would like to make the identifier of a message in the database unique. However I'm not sure that it is really unique. What if it is unique only for a user or for one EWS server? Unfortunately [the EWS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/itemid) tells nothing about that.

Do you know anything regarding the topic?

Comment: Yes, maybe it is unique only for one server. However, I'm not sure that what if you add a  another id e.g. "etag" as a primary key. Or add a custom ID by your define in your database.

Comment: The EWS ItemId is intended to be opaque, however it seems the EWS ItemId contains a mailbox GUID and an EntryId based on what has been said about it.  If it includes a mailbox GUID, that should be unique. If you are going to store them in a database, there are specific notes in this article about how EWS ItemIds may change: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-identifiers-in-exchange